# NullException when binding a property of a nested controller

Tags: javafx

I want to get the value of a textfield that is changed in one fxml interface (nested.fxml) in another view (main.fxml). I have defined a nestedController like this:

```
`   
package reproduced;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class NestedController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private TextField changeValue;

    public ObjectProperty<ObjectStringToUpdate> attVal= new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Override
    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        this.changeValue.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
     
        public void changed(ObservableValue<?> ov, Object t, Object t1) {
            ObjectStringToUpdate newValue = new ObjectStringToUpdate();  
            newValue.setAttValNested(t1.toString());
            attVal.setValue(newValue);
        }
 
});
}
```

}`

And the mainController is:

```
`import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class MainController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    public BorderPane mainBorderPane;
    Property<ObjectStringToUpdate> attVal =  new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
     
    @FXML public NestedController nestedController;//injected nested controller
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        ObjectProperty<ObjectStringToUpdate> binding = nestedController.attVal;
        ((Property<ObjectStringToUpdate>) this.attVal).bind(binding);
 
        }
    @FXML
   public void testVal() {
        System.out.println(this.attVal.getValue().attValNested);// this when called returns null value because this.attaVal is null
        /*Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "attValNested" because the return value of "javafx.beans.property.Property.getValue()" is null
*/
    }
    @FXML 
    public void openNestedView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loaderOfTabs = new 
                FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/nested.fxml"));
        AnchorPane tabPane = (AnchorPane) loaderOfTabs.load();
        mainBorderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
        }
 
}`
```

Then the object:

```
`public class ObjectStringToUpdate {
    public String attValNested;
    
    public String getAttValNested() {
        return attValNested;
    }
    
    public void setAttValNested(String attVal) {
        this.attValNested = attVal;
        }   
    }`
```

The app main entry is:

```
`package reproduced;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UInterface2 extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        String fxmlFile = "main.fxml";
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent rootNode = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fxmlFile));
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, 1024, 843);
        stage.setTitle("reproduced");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}`
```

fxmls:

main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="rootAnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="843.0" prefWidth="1224.0" fx:controller="reproduced.MainController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="mainBorderPane" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="843.0" prefWidth="1024.0">
         <top>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openNestedView" text="open nested View" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
      <Button fx:id="testVal" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#testVal" text="test" />
      <Label fx:id="showValue" text="Label" />
   </children>
   <fx:include fx:id="nested" source="nested.fxml" visible="false" />
</AnchorPane>`
```

nested.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="rootAnchorPaneInner" fx:controller="reproduced.NestedController">
   <children>
      <TextField xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:id="changeValue" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>`
```

I have also included the fxml component of NestedController in main.fxml properly.

But when I update the textfield value in the nested controller and try to call it in the main Controller through a button click I get null exception: `the return value of "javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty.getValue()" is null`

I expect the `this.attVal` at `MainController.testVal()` to return the value as changed in the `NestedController`.

Comment: @kleopatra The injection naming is correct. The controller associated with an `fx:include` is the `fx:id ` with “Controller” appended.

Comment: @James_D ahh, thanks - didn't find it in the spec (lame excuse for probably not looking thoroughly enough ;)

Comment: @kleopatra It is barely there, but see https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers and https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#CONTROLLER_SUFFIX in combination with https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/constant-values.html#javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.CONTROLLER_SUFFIX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading the FXML file `nested.fxml` twice. Once via the `<fx:include>` element in `main.fxml`, and then subsequently each time you press the "open nested view" button.

The instance of `nested.fxml` loaded via `<fx:include>` is not actually visible, since you (for some reason) have `visible="false"` in the `<fx:include>` element. The instance that appears when the button is pressed is a different instance entirely, created via the call to `loaderOfTabs.load()`.

The nested controller, of course, is associated with the instance created by `<fx:include>`. Since that is not visible, the user can never type in its text field, and so its text field's `textProperty.onChanged` handler can never be invoked. Consequently, the value of `attVal` in that instance of the controller is never initialized: i.e. in that controller instance `attVal.getValue()` will always be null, and so when you invoke `attVal.getValue().attValNested` you of course get a `NullPointerException`.

I don't understand why you have multiple instances of the `nested.fxml` UI. Either use `<fx:include>` or load it in code. If you want to use `<fx:include>` and keep it invisible until the user presses a button (why???), just do:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable{

    // ...

    @FXML public NestedController nestedController;//injected nested controller
    @FXML private AnchorPane nested;


    // ...

    public void openNestedView() throws IOException {
        nested.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

---

Conversely, if you want to load the FXML when the button is pressed, remove the `<fx:include>` from `main.fxml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:id="rootAnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="843.0" prefWidth="1224.0" fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.nestedprop.MainController">
    <children>
        <BorderPane fx:id="mainBorderPane" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="843.0" prefWidth="1024.0">
            <top>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openNestedView" text="open nested View" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
            </top>

        </BorderPane>
        <Button fx:id="testVal" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#testVal" text="test" />
        <Label fx:id="showValue" text="Label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and then just get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` and perform the binding when you get it:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class MainController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    public BorderPane mainBorderPane;
    Property<ObjectStringToUpdate> attVal =  new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private NestedController nestedController;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
    @FXML
    public void testVal() {
        System.out.println(this.attVal.getValue().attValNested);
    }
    @FXML
    public void openNestedView() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loaderOfTabs = new
                FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("nested.fxml"));
        AnchorPane tabPane = (AnchorPane) loaderOfTabs.load();

        nestedController = loaderOfTabs.getController();

        ObjectProperty<ObjectStringToUpdate> binding = nestedController.attVal;
        this.attVal.bind(binding);

        mainBorderPane.setCenter(tabPane);

    }

}
```

Comment: I see that even with a full working code for the example, you are not helping. I am discussing ObjectProperty and binding and nested controllers and you are talking about component being invisible. Not helping...

Comment: you say : The instance that appears when the button is pressed is a different instance entirely, created via the call to loaderOfTabs.load().
Is there another way to call nested.fxml?

Comment: I use `<fx:include>` because of nestedController in mainController. and I load in code to refresh it (load a new one)

Comment: The point is that when I bind in mainController the property, I expect it to be updated (if the user did in nested.fxml) in main.fxml as well

Comment: @ites Please make the changes I suggest, run it,  press the “open nested view”, type in the text field, press the “test” button and see if it works (spoiler alert: it does).

Comment: no it does not, and when if I remove `<fx:include>` it will throw an exception because of the nestedcontroller. Does this also mean that the code for binding the object property is right?

Comment: @ites I didn’t say to remove `<fx:include>`. Literally make the code updates I made in the answer, so that the instance of `nested.FXML` is the *only* instance.

Comment: *”I am discussing ObjectProperty”*. My answer explains, carefully, that you never call `setValue(…)` on the `ObjectProperty` instance you are binding to. I explained why that is, which necessarily involves the fact that you never make the included `nested.fxml ` visible. If you don’t want the actual answer to your question, why are you posting here?

Comment: <fx:include id:"nested"> is ensuring this  `@FXML public NestedController nestedController;//injected nested controller` in mainController, how could I remove it ?

Comment: @ites Why do you want to remove it? My answer explicitly says “if you want to keep the `<fx:include>`” and then provides the exact code to make this work with it there.

Comment: If you do want to remove it, then load `nested.fxml ` in the code *instead* and retrieve the controller from the `FXMLLoader` instead of injecting it.

Comment: yes  nested.setVisible(true); made the trick, but what if I wanted to reload a brand new nested AnchorPane?

Comment: At least, that shows that I knew how to bind a property (I did it based on none of SO examples) and that most importanly I am not lazy (as you said in the previous post) as I made a full code example for you to answer it ;)

Comment: this phrase is key "The instance that appears when the button is pressed is a different instance entirely, created via the call to loaderOfTabs.load()." the binded value is not found or is null because a new instance of nested in created instead of the actual one

Comment: *”what if I wanted to reload a brand new nested AnchorPane”*. You already posted code that loads the FXML directly. As I said, just get the controller from the `FXMLLoader`. I will update the answer with that option when I am back at a computer.

Comment: @ites *"this phrase is key"* Well, yes, that's why I included it. *"because a new instance of nested in created instead of the actual one"* I don't know what you mean by *"the actual one"* here. Each time you load the FXML, new instances of the objets defined in it and a new controller instance are created. It's hard to see how else it would work.

Comment: @ites Anyway, I have updated the answer with the other option. You should be able to remove your downvote now (which I assume you don't need, since you have accepted the answer).